# Get specific portion of a URL string

Tags: javascript

Here is a working code I have to get a specific portion of a URL string:

```js
const movieName = "frozen_2019";
const courseName = "olaf_is_enjoying_living_his_dream_1";


const source = "your majesty from https://example.com/english/courses/frozen_2019/olaf_is_enjoying_living_his_dream_1/voices/references/translate/do%20you%20hear%20that.mp3";

console.log(getSourceError(source)); // result

function getSourceError(source) {

  const a = source.substring(source.indexOf(courseName) + courseName.length + 1);
  const b = a.substring(a.lastIndexOf("/"));
  return a.replace(b , "");

}
```

Although it's working as expected but I think there should be a cleaner solution to do this...

As you see I want the string between `courseName` and the `file name` at the end of the URl.

Comment: What if you can do something like `source .split('/').splice(7,3).join('/')`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completly sure what you mean by cleaner solution but this is a one-liner line with regex supposing you got the same variable names like in your snippet. Is this what you wanted to achieve? You can trim the last and first character to remove the slashes if needed.

```js
const source = "your majesty from https://example.com/english/courses/frozen_2019/olaf_is_enjoying_living_his_dream_1/voices/references/translate/do%20you%20hear%20that.mp3";
const courseName = "olaf_is_enjoying_living_his_dream_1";
let extracted = source.match("(?<="+courseName+").*\/");
console.log(extracted);
```

Answer (score 1):

> As you see I want the string between courseName and the file name at
> the end of the URL.

When manipulating URL strings, it's often a good idea to split the string into an array using:

```
let myURLArray = myURLString.split('/');
```

Then, in this situation, you can use:

- `indexOf()`
- `splice()`
- `join()`

to return the section of the URL that you want.

**Working Example:**

```js
const courseName = "olaf_is_enjoying_living_his_dream_1";
const source = "your majesty from https://example.com/english/courses/frozen_2019/olaf_is_enjoying_living_his_dream_1/voices/references/translate/do%20you%20hear%20that.mp3";

let sourceArray = source.split('/');
let courseNameIndex = sourceArray.indexOf(courseName);
let urlSectionArray = sourceArray.splice((courseNameIndex + 1), ((sourceArray.length - 1) - courseNameIndex - 1));

let urlSection = urlSectionArray.join('/');
console.log(urlSection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi if your source is consinstent with its structure you can split and join the pieces you require.

```
source.split('/').splice(7,3).join('/')
```